# Convert list to dictionary using same default key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list which looks like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to iterate through that list to get a dictionary like:

```
dict = {'jobs': [{'id':'a'}], [{'id':'b'}], [{'id':'c'}]}
```

I tried looping through the elements of the list, like:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict = {'jobs':[{}]}
for key in range(len(lst)):
    dict['jobs'][key]['id'] = list[key]

print(dict)
```

But I get an out of range error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
{'jobs' : [{'id' : x} for x in lst]}

# {'jobs': [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'c'}]}
```